# find correct mimetype of file in python

Tags: python-3.x

find mime type of file by python. i tried it by magic module it, but detect wrong mime type. i also tried it by mime types module it also detect wrong. anyone knows another way ?

```
def MagicMIME(n,filename):
    mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
    mime = mime.from_file(filename)
    print(mime)
filename = 'test.css'
MagicMIME(filename)
```

i take `css` file it `shows :text/plain`,but actuality mime type is `text/css`
what actually i want if i change the extension it should be detect correct `mime type`

Comment: Please avoid using totally unrelated tags (fixed).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [libmagic. text/plain instead of text/javascript text/css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494501/libmagic-text-plain-instead-of-text-javascript-text-css)